# Constructing single select statement that returns order depends on the value of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
Table1
Id bigint primary key identity(1,1)
Status nvarchar(20)
```

Insert dummy data

```
Insert into Table1 values ('Open') --1
Insert into Table1 values ('Open') --2
Insert into Table1 values ('Grabbed') --3
Insert into Table1 values ('Closed') --4
Insert into Table1 values ('Closed') --5
Insert into Table1 values ('Open') --6
```

How would I construct a single select statement which orders the data where records with `'Grabbed'` status is first, followed by `'Closed'`, followed by `'Open'` in SQL Server

Output:

```
Id    Status
3     Grabbed
4     Closed
5     Closed
1     Open
2     Open
6     Open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
select *
from yourTable
order by case when Status = 'Grabbed' then 1
              when Status = 'Closed' then 2
              when Status = 'Open' then 3
              else 4 end
    , Id;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0612a/2)

---

Another way is to using CTE like this:

```
;with cte as (
  select 'Grabbed' [Status], 1 [order]
  union all select 'Closed', 2
  union all select 'Open', 3
)
select t.*
from yourTable t
left join cte 
  on t.[Status] = cte.[Status]
order by cte.[order], Id;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0612a/4)

Comment: Hope to help ;).

Comment: This may work, but is a very bad approach... The status should be normalized into a related side table...

Comment: @Shnugo In a better approach I'll prefer using a CTE instead of a related side table ;).

Comment: @shA.t This is just *syntactical sugar* but no real improvement... **The design is wrong** and against the principles of normalisation.... Such values ought to live in a lookup table!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done much better with a properly **normalized** design:

Do not store your `Status` as a textual content. Just imagine a typo (a row with `Grabed`)...

Further more a lookup table allows you to add side data, e.g. a sort order.

```
CREATE TABLE StatusLookUp(StatusID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY /*you should name your constraints!*/
                         ,StatusName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                         ,SortRank INT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO StatusLookUp VALUES
 ('Open',99) --ID=1
,('Closed',50)--ID=2
,('Grabbed',10)--ID=3

CREATE TABLE Table1(Id bigint primary key identity(1,1) /*you should name your constraints!*/
                   ,StatusID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES StatusLookUp(StatusID));

Insert into Table1 values (1) --1
Insert into Table1 values (1) --2
Insert into Table1 values (3) --3
Insert into Table1 values (2) --4
Insert into Table1 values (2) --5
Insert into Table1 values (1) --6

SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN StatusLookUp AS s ON t1.StatusID=s.StatusID
ORDER BY s.SortRank;
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the simplest method uses a string:

```
order by charindex(status, 'Grabbed,Closed,Open')
```

or:

```
order by charindex(',' + status + ',', ',Grabbed,Closed,Open,')
```

If you are going to put values in the query, I think the easiest way uses `values()`:

```
select t1.*
from t1 left join
     (values ('Grabbed', 1), ('Closed', 2), ('Open', 3)) v(status, priority)
     on t1.status = v.status
order by coalesce(v.priority, 4);
```

Finally.  This need suggests that you should have a reference table for statuses.  Rather than putting the string name in other tables, put an id.  The reference table can have the priority as well as other information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Id,status from tablename where status='Grabbed'
union
select Id,status from tablename where status='Closed'
union
select Id,status from tablename where status='Open'
```